# Scrollable tbody with all other elements fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaYfW/1/)

I am trying to keep the `header`, `thead`, and `footer` elements fixed. When extra elements are added inside the `tbody` and it overflows, only the `tbody` should get a scrollbar.

I have tried setting an `overflow` property for `tbody`, but it's not working. How can I achieve the desired effect?

```
tbody {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: block;`, exact height, and `overflow: scroll` seems to do the trick. You can check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaYfW/7/). I also had to comment your hide statement to show the rest of the rows.

```
tbody {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 140px; /* height that you want the tbody to remain */
    display: block;
}
```

**------EDIT**

Ok, did a restructure of the approach. With some fixed positioning on your header and footer, and compensation for those heights with margins for your table, it seems to be closer to what you are looking for. Head on over to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UaYfW/59/) and let's see if we got closer to the end result. :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi i do my best with this code: **http://jsfiddle.net/UaYfW/52/**

The problem is you need to set `width` on the `td` an `th` to make them fit. But you can do it with %.

**Edit**

What I do one on one of the files :

HTML ----- Make a `div` arround the table with the class `inner`

CSS ------ Add this properties

```
.inner {
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
.table td:first-child {
  width:15%;
}
.table td:last-child {
  width:18%;
}
```

I've set the width to the last and first columns just to make it fit with the head.

JS ------ Add this

```
var hinner=parseInt($('#wrap').css('height'),10)-198+"px";
 $('.inner').css({
    'height': hinner,
 });

var $thead= $('.table thead').remove();
 $('header').after("<table/>");
 $('header').next().append($thead);
 $('header').next().css ({
   'line-height' : '38px',
   'width' : '100%'
 });
```